# ecommerce tracking for a hybris site

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, sap-commerce-cloud

I have installed the google analytics plugin in my hybris site.But I am not getting my events captured in my google analytics.What could be the possible problem.I am using Universal Google analytics.

Comment: Are you seeing the tags show upon on the page? Is the domain you are testing with also a domain that is registered for the google analytics account?

Comment: Yes.We are getting product impressions and product details.Cart events are not getting captured.window.mediator.subscribe('trackAddToCart',function(data){trackAddToCart_GTM,()})..Here function(data) is what function??need help.

Comment: The 'function(data)' part is just an anonymous function call that will be executed when the subscribe line is executed. The line you pasted appears to be custom code, so you will need to work with your team to figure on how the subscribe message is supposed to work. Standard google ecommerce analytical tagging is described here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingEcommerce

Answer (score 0):

I think the Universal Analytics won't work. Here is some [reference](https://www.hybris.com/en/partner/hybris-extend/google-analytics) about the google analytics...